# jquery ajax logout security

Tags: php, jquery

When a user logs in, a session id is generated accordingly. There is a 'logout' link on the page. On clicking the link a jquery ajax method is called to execute a php file which just unsets the session id variable.

If any user uses Firebug or any such tool to see the called-in file address, then s/he can just put the file address in the address bar and the press the 'Enter' key to execute the php file which will consequently log the user out which I do not want to happen.

How to prevent the user from doing that? Http_referrer or any such thing?

Scripting language is php.

Comment: So a person barges onto someone else's computer, fires up Firebug's NET console, start digging for logout.php links, and start banging enter keys? Do I have that right? And what do you mean (practically, show us) by "called-in file address"? `logout.php?sessionid=blahblah`?

Comment: 'person' could be the logged-in user.

Comment: Well. I'm going to go out on a limb here and say you probably don't have anything of consequence to worry about, and should not let it get you... Before you waste too much time on it.

Comment: just calls logout.php . The page unsets the session variable holding the session id

Comment: While not PHP-based, the ASP.NET MVC 3 book does discuss techniques to avoid the situation to which you refer.  You could probably take those ideas and implement them in your particular system.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concern but it seems to me like you are worried about a person logging out by going to the log out script's url directly vs clicking a log out link. If that's the case then why are you worried? They are just logging themselves out, not another user. So what's wrong with that?

Comment: Honestly, I'm being straight with you here: Don't worry about it. And @JakeRow123 I think gets it.

Comment: may be nothing to worry about in this case. But , just to find out such a process, I think Scott has done that.

Comment: @jonnyGold, Can you shed a bit light on the technique please?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed The main idea is to do a post and render a one-time use value in a hidden form field and validate that it is kosher when the server sees it.  Avoids XSS logout hammering.

Comment: 'kosher'? How to send a hidden value in jquery ajax call ? Is scott's answer what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the AJAX call POST a variable to the PHP page, which the PHP page checks bofore logging the user out.

If it is a matter of making sure they redirect to the home page after logging out, make the a link to the logout page, then use PHP to send `header("Location: home.php");`. This has the added bonus of still working even if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: still then it is  possible to see the jquery / javascript ajax code and make  a script  with that variable to log the user out. Actually is there any better  way out there?

Comment: Just have a link to a logout page, then use php to redirect them to the homepage. Also, then no JavaScript is required. (I reworded my answer slightly.) If you are asking if there is a better way using the AJAX call, you could use the JS to set a cookie just before the call to PHP page, and the PHP looks for the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are afraid that someone else sends your sites logout link to some of your users. To make sure that your user really wants to logout you can require a post variable which has to be send to the logout page. Of course that post variable should be a unique and secret value, e.g. a random hash that is generated for each session.